# MeteorJS Change Web Root

Tags: javascript, meteor

Currently my app structure looks like this-

```
.meteor/
client/
    ... public files
server/
typings/
tsconfig.json
```

And when I run meteor with the `meteor` command it serves my project from this directory. So client files are accessed via `client/assets/images/myimg.png`. Not only is the `client` portion redundant but It seems like a security issue as I'm then assuming `server/*` is also accessible. How can I update meteor so the web root begins at `client/` ?

I did try google first. I either couldn't find anything or didn't understand what I was reading.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention for storing public assets (e.g. an image) is to put them in the root level folder `public`.  If you put image.png in the public folder, it will be accessible at /image.png.  You'll also want to look into using a router to appropriately serve your routes/assets.

Comment: Using Angular2 Router and not using Blaze. Is it then necessary to use the Meteor Router?

Comment: Hmm I'm not 100% sure about routing using Angular with Meteor, sorry. :-/